# Truncated Sphere Spectra and their Modules

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, stable-homotopy, derived-algebraic-geometry

I'm trying to use truncations $\tau_{\leq n}S$ of the sphere spectrum to ``interpolate'' between $\DeclareMathOperator{\H}{H} \H\mathbb{Z}$ and $S$, and I am struggling to find references for questions that feel like they should be well-known.

Specifically I'm interested in what's known about:

- The relationship between $X$ and $X \otimes \tau_{\leq n}S$. Does the homology theory associated to $\tau_{\leq n}S$ have a more concrete interpretation for e.g. $n = 1$?
- Given a map $\H A \to \H B$, what conditions does this map need to satisfy to be a map of $\tau_{\leq n}S$-modules for $n > 0$?

I would really appreciate any relevant resources/papers!

Comment: What is $HA$ or $HB$ ? Is it an Eilenberg-MacLane spectrum ?

Comment: yes! sorry for not clarifying that -- both Eilenberg-Maclane spectra, although not necessarily in the same dimension.

Comment: See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/403218/what-is-the-homotopy-category-of-the-sphere-spectrum/403221#403221) for a description of $\tau_{\leq 1} S$ as a symmetric monoidal groupoid. I haven't thought about the associated homology theory.