# What comes next in the sequence "symmetric algebras, exterior algebras, divided power algebras, ..."?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ra.rings-and-algebras, exterior-algebra, symmetric-algebras, divided-powers

This question was posed by A Rock and a Hard Place in [this discussion](https://mathoverflow.net/a/403274), where they mentioned the isomorphisms
\begin{align*}
    \mathrm{L}\,\mathrm{Sym}^n_R(M[1])       &\cong (\mathrm{L}\,{\textstyle\bigwedge}^n_R (M))[n],\\
    \mathrm{L}\,{\textstyle\bigwedge}^n_R(M[1]) &\cong (\mathrm{L}\,\Gamma^n_R(M))[n].
\end{align*}

From what I understand, these were first proved independently by Bousfield in [*Homogeneous functors and their derived functors*](https://math.mit.edu/%7Ehrm/manuscripts/bousfield-homogeneous.pdf) and by Quillen in [*On the (co)-homology of rings*](https://doi.org/10.1090/pspum%2F017%2F0257068). Two other references are 7.2.1 of Quillen's [*Homology of Commutative Rings*](http://library.lol/main/431993A37AE5E9434640931094C59362) and I.4.3.2.1 (p. 111) of Illusie's [*Complexe Cotangent et Deformations I*](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540056867).

> **Question.** What comes after divided power algebras in the sequence $\mathrm{Sym}^\bullet_R(M)$, $\bigwedge^\bullet_R(M)$, $\Gamma^\bullet_R(M)$, $\ldots$, in the sense of there existing also algebras $\mathsf{A}^\bullet_\mathsf{3}$, $\mathsf{A}^\bullet_{\mathsf{4}}$, $\ldots$, together with isomorphisms of the form
>
> $$\mathrm{L}\,\mathsf{A}^n_\mathsf{k}(M)\cong (\mathrm{L}\,\mathsf{A}^{n+1}_{\mathsf{k}}(M))[n],$$
>
> where $\mathsf{A}^\bullet_\mathsf{0}\cong\mathrm{Sym}^\bullet_R$, $\mathsf{A}^\bullet_\mathsf{1}\cong\bigwedge^\bullet_R$, and $\mathsf{A}^\bullet_\mathsf{2}\cong\Gamma^\bullet_R$?

One hint was given by Sanath [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/403272/is-there-a-spectral-exterior-algebra-construction-in-higher-algebra/403274#comment1032752_403274): the algebra $\mathsf{A}^\bullet_{\mathsf{n}}$ is related to the homology of $\mathrm{K}(\mathbb{Z},n)$, some computations of which may be found in the table in page 67 of Breen–Mikhailov–Touzé's [*Derived functors of the divided power functors*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.5676v2.pdf#page=67).

Comment: (While this question was discussed [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/403272) already, I think it's worthwhile to re-ask it as a separate question, in particular considering that 1) this gives a permanent home for it (and there's always the chance that someone who knows the answer, or a partial one, might end up bumping upon it) and 2) it is potentially of interest also to people in areas besides SAG/HA)